# How to Exclude a Field When Using an Inclusion Projection in MongoDB/Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a lookup query in which I use an inclusion projection to filter out posts where published = false. I also need exclude a field, but I can't workout how to do it given the inclusion projection.

This is my aggregation:

```
{
...
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'photos', 
            'localField': '_id', 
            'foreignField': 'postId', 
            'as': 'photoData'
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 1, 
            'field1': 1, 
            'field2': 1, 
            'field3': 1, 
            'photoData': {
                '_id': 0, // ** I am trying to exclude this field **
                '$filter': {
                    'input': '$photoData', 
                    'as': 'photo', 
                    'cond': {
                        '$ne': [
                            '$$photo.published', false
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to exclude the '_id' field in the photoData lookup. Doing it like this with the '_id: 0' in the photoData projection gives a "Cannot do exclusion on field _id in inclusion projection". I've tried a few other methods as well with no success. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi Wernfried, how would skipping '_id: 0' exclude this field, please?

Comment: Add stage `{ $unset: "photoData._id" }`

Comment: Excellent, many thanks Wernfried, that works perfectly (although not in the aggregation builder on MongoDB, you have to just put it in the code). I will mark it as correct if you write it as an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove fields with this stage:

```
{ $unset: "photoData._id" }
```